# Is there a policy using which we can prevent user from clearing any app's storage in Android Management APIs (AMAPI)?

Tags: android-management-api

By going to app info we get the clear storage button using which a user can clear the storage of that application. In AMAPI do we have any policy using which we can stop user from clearing the storage of any particular application.

FORCE_INSTALLED install type does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing users from modifying application data from Settings app, such as clearing the storage of a specific application, is currently supported for KIOSK apps only. The team is currently investigating similar feature requests and we will consider this feedback for prioritization.